# UI Freezes When Try to Update textbox in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading, user-interface

I have a code that has a text box and a button, when i press the button, the code update the text box and after words sleep for 5 seconds, in those seconds the ui is freezing 
I tried with delegates, and threading but nothing works
This is the code with delegates:

MainWindow.vb

```
Class MainWindow
    Delegate Sub MySubDelegate(ByVal x As String)
    Private m_engine As Engine

    Public Sub New()
        m_engine = New Engine(AddressOf WriteToLog)
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.DataContext = m_engine.GetViewModel()

    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteToLog(str As String)
        Dim vv As ViewModel = CType(DataContext, ViewModel)
        vv.Log = str
    End Sub

    Private Sub clicked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        m_engine.TimingRecord()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Engine.vb

```
Private m_viewModel As New ViewModel
Private _msd As MainWindow.MySubDelegate

Public Sub New()

End Sub

Sub New(msd As MainWindow.MySubDelegate)
    _msd = msd
End Sub

Public Function GetViewModel() As ViewModel
    Return m_viewModel
End Function

Public Sub TimingRecord()        
    _msd("aaaaa")
    SetText()
End Sub


Public Sub SetText()
    Thread.Sleep(5000)
End Sub
```

viewModel.vb

```
Public Class ViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Private m_log As String
    Public Property Log As String
        Get
            Return m_log
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_log = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is the code with thread:

MainWindow.vb

```
Delegate Sub MySubDelegate(ByVal x As String)
Private m_engine As Engine

Public Sub New()
    m_engine = New Engine(AddressOf WriteToLog)
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.DataContext = m_engine.GetViewModel()

End Sub

Public Sub WriteToLog(str As String)
    Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub() CType(DataContext, ViewModel).Log = str)
    'Dim vv As ViewModel = CType(DataContext, ViewModel)
    'vv.Log = str
End Sub

Private Sub clicked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    m_engine.TimingRecord()
End Sub
```

Engine.vb

```
Public Class Engine
    Private m_viewModel As New ViewModel    
    Private m_thread As Thread
    Private _msd As MainWindow.MySubDelegate

    Public Sub New(msd As MainWindow.MySubDelegate)
        _msd = msd
    End Sub

    Public Function GetViewModel() As ViewModel
        Return m_viewModel
    End Function

    Public Sub TimingRecord()
        m_thread = New Thread(AddressOf DoRecordThread)
        m_thread.IsBackground = True
        m_thread.Start("aa")
        SetText()
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetText()
        Thread.Sleep(5000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DoRecordThread(str As String)
        _msd(str)
        'm_viewModel.Log = str
    End Sub
End Class
```

The ViewModel Stay The same. I'm using wpf so i bind the Log into the textbox and with simple code it works.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: `SLEEP` causes your thread to, well, sleep. If the thread is your UI then it is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: Why are you doing `Thread.Sleep(5000)`?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the thread.sleep comes instead of a very long run like for from.1 to 100000000, i put the sleep inside the new thread the ui didnt froze but he text box not updating can you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep` causing the issue.  It blocks the UI thread that makes the UI frozen.

Have the long running task in different thread and once completed Update the UI(`TextBox`) with `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.

Sample Code to update the UI from background thread with `Dispatcher` :

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { Textbox1.Text = result; }))
```

This is not a right way but I hope this is what you are looking for.

**Update**

Also, there is another way, you can use builtin `BackgroundWorker`.

```
//Add the namespace
using System.ComponentModel;

//Declare
private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

//Initialize
worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;


//method declaration
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   worker.ReportProgress(0, "Process started");
   // run all background tasks here
}

private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Progress update with e.UserState.ToString();
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, 
                                       RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  //update ui once worker complete his work
}

//Invoke
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Yes put the thread.sleep inside new thread does solve the freezing problem but the text does not update, and i want to have the possbility to write to a text before the long run(like write "start process" to a log text box)

Comment: You can have the code `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { Textbox1.Text = result; }))` inside the new thread that will update the text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by put the thread.sleep but very foolish of me in the viewmodel class i accidently delete the property changed now it is working perfectly thank you all for helping